# How Do I Effectively Filter Information?

Tags: forms, filter, time, limit, splunk

**I want to preface with the fact that I am a total noob at Splunk, so please bear with me.**

I am trying to make a dashboard that shows the on-call for each organization/team. It lists their name, contact info, the start of when they are on call, and the end of when they are on call.

**Ex of what it should look like:**
(Select org(s): abc )

| org | team | username | OnCallStart | OnCallEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | aa-team | bob2 | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 | 2023-05-02T08:00:00-7:00 |

**The issue is (other than me not being able to figure out how to get their respective teams listed currently) is that it looks more like this:** *(ignore the dates being the exact same, just giving an idea of the format)*

| org | team | username | OnCallStart | OnCallEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc |  | bob2 | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 | 2023-05-02T08:00:00-7:00 |
| 123 |  |  | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 |
|  |  |  | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 |
|  |  |  | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 |
|  |  |  | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 |
|  |  |  | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 |
|  |  |  | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 | 2023-05-02T08:00:00-7:00 |
|  |  |  | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 |
|  |  |  | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 |
|  |  |  | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 |
|  |  |  | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 | 2023-05-01T08:00:00-7:00 |

I have a multiselect option with a submit button so that I can filter by orgs, however if for example I filtered by "abc" org, it would show bob2 but have both "abc" and "123" orgs listed.

How can I control the orgs shown when a user is a part of multiple orgs?
How can I limit the number of oncallstart and oncallend times listed to a single line that correlates to the particular org that it matches with?

I tried seeing if I could use something like | head 1
But that doesn't seem to be what I want based on this: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SCS/current/SearchReference/HeadCommandOverview#How_the_head_command_works

I don't know where to locate props.conf to use something like TRUNCATE, not even sure if that's what should be used in this instance or not.
https://community.splunk.com/t5/Getting-Data-In/Size-limit-for-an-event/m-p/16410

I considered limiting in the source code by using something like 1 but that just limits it to show one user per page, still listing the multiple orgs (despite filtering for a particular one) and the multiple start and end times.

Would it be some kind of query parameter?
https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/DashApp/0.9.0/DashApp/dsOpt

EDIT: Added query SPL

```
index=blahblah-oncall sourcetype=blahblahschedule 
| spath org 
| search org=* 
| spath "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username" 
| search "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username"=* 
| spath "teams{}.team.name" 
| search "teams{}.team.name"=* 
| rename "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username" as Username 
| table Username, org,team, OnCallStart, OnCallEnd
| append [search index=blahblah-oncall sourcetype=blahblahschedule 
  | spath "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username" 
  | search "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username"=* 
  | spath "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.end" 
  | search "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.end"=* 
  | rename "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.end" as OnCallEnd 
  | rename "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username" as Username 
  | table Username, org,team, OnCallStart, OnCallEnd] 
| stats values(*) as * by Username
| append [search index=blahblah-oncall sourcetype=blahblahschedule 
  | spath "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username" 
  | search "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username"=* 
  | spath "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.start" 
  | search "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.start"=* 
  | rename "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.start" as OnCallStart 
  | rename "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username" as Username 
  | table Username, org,team, OnCallStart, OnCallEnd] 
| stats values(*) as * by Username
| append [search index=blahblah-oncall sourcetype=blahblahschedule 
  | spath "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username" 
  | search "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username"=* 
  | spath "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.end" 
  | search "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.end"=* 
  | rename "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.end" as OnCallEnd 
  | rename "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username" as Username 
  | table Username, org,team, OnCallStart, OnCallEnd] 
| stats values(*) as * by Username
| stats values(*) as * by Username 
| table org,team, Username, OnCallStart, OnCallEnd 
| search $orgs$ 
| sort org
```

Comment: Please share the SPL you are using to produce the current output.

Comment: What does your source data look like? Is it a lookup table? Something else?

Comment: Source data looks like a tree in the sense that I click the little plus button and more info drops down:

{ [-]
   org: abc123
   schedules: [ [-]
     { [-]
       overrides: [ [+]
       ]
       policy: { [+]
       }
       schedule: [ [-]
         { [-]
           onCallType: rotation_group
           onCallUser: { [-]

Comment: (it's long so I will have to break it into parts)


index=blahblah-oncall sourcetype=blahblahschedule
| spath org | search org=*
| spath "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username" | search "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username"=*
| spath "teams{}.team.name" | search "teams{}.team.name"=*
| rename "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username" as Username
| table Username, org,team, OnCallStart, OnCallEnd

Comment: | append [search index=blahblah-oncall sourcetype=blahblahschedule
| spath "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username" | search "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username"=*
| spath "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.end" | search "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.end"=*
| rename "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.end" as OnCallEnd
| rename "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username" as Username
| table Username, org,team, OnCallStart, OnCallEnd] | stats values(*) as * by Username

Comment: | append [search index=blahblah-oncall sourcetype=blahblahschedule
| spath "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username" | search "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username"=*
| spath "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.start" | search "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.start"=*
| rename "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.start" as OnCallStart
| rename "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username" as Username
| table Username, org,team, OnCallStart, OnCallEnd] | stats values(*) as * by Username

Comment: | append [search index=blahblah-oncall sourcetype=blahblahschedule
| spath "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username" | search "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username"=*
| spath "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.end" | search "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.end"=*
| rename "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.rolls{}.end" as OnCallEnd
| rename "teams{}.schedules{}.schedule{}.onCallUser.username" as Username
| table Username, org,team, OnCallStart, OnCallEnd] | stats values(*) as * by Username

Comment: | stats values(*) as * by Username
| table org,team, Username, OnCallStart, OnCallEnd | search $orgs$ | sort org

Comment: If you see "little plus button" then you are not looking at the raw data.  Click the "Show raw text" link in Splunk to view the unformatted data.